# SSH public keys not working; my home directory is encrypted

Tags: ssh, home, ecryptfs, public-key-authentication

I installed Ubuntu LTS 14.04 server edition on a remote computer, and added my local public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote computer. I found that I still needed to use password to log in the remote computer, even after setting the permission of `~/.ssh` to 700, and `~/.ssh/*` to 600 on the remote computer. However, once I log in, I can start using public key for authorization for other ssh sessions.

My home directory is encrypted.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is your home directory encrypted?

Comment: @steeldriver yes, my home directory is encrypted

Comment: @shva [See if this helps you](http://stephen.rees-carter.net/thought/encrypted-home-directories-ssh-key-authentication)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution from the link I posted in my comment. This comes from [here](http://stephen.rees-carter.net/thought/encrypted-home-directories-ssh-key-authentication), which references this [superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/61057/ssh-with-authorized-keys-to-an-ubuntu-system-with-encrypted-homedir).

Create `.ssh` folder in `/home` for the keys to be stored

```
sudo mkdir /home/.ssh
```

Move existing authorized_keys file into `.ssh` dir as username

```
sudo mv ~/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/.ssh/username
```

Create symbolic link to authorized_keys file in user `.ssh` dir

```
ln -s /home/.ssh/username ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Update `sshd_config` file to set the new path for the `authorized_keys` file

```
sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Change the `AuthorizedKeysFile` line to:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile      /home/.ssh/%u
```

Reboot the computer

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Login to your server and you should be presented with a minimal un-decrypted home directory... You will need to create and edit a .profile file in there to get `ecryptfs` to mount your home directory.

```
sudo vim ~/.profile
```

Add these lines:

```
ecryptfs-mount-private
cd /home/username
```

Log out/Restart, and go back in again. You should be prompted for your password after SSH key auth, and then be presented with your decrypted home directory.

You should now be able to login using SSH keys every time, no matter if your home dir is decrypted or not.